# Saving the result of an array.protoype.foreEach() into a variable getting undefined

Tags: javascript, foreach, ecmascript-5

How do I get newData to equal the object array that is produced by the `forEach()`? It works if I define `var result = []` globally and `console.log(result);`

```
var paragraphs = ["this is a p", "%%this is an h2", "%this is an h1"];

var newData = paragraphs.forEach(function(x) {
    var result = [];
    var header = 0;
    while (x.charAt(header) === "%")
     header++;

    if (header > 0) {
        result.push({type:"h" + header, content: x.slice(header)});
    } else { 
        result.push({type: "p", content: x}); 
    }
        return result;

});

console.log(newData); // undefined
```

Comment: `forEach` is like a `for` loop. You want `map`.

Comment: Thx - I am familiar with map - I should have noted that - sorry - but I am trying to understand the logic why I can not get it to return a value in this case. Its just bugging me - or should I just drop it.

Comment: Look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: @jamie: `forEach` doesn't do anything with the return value of the callback function. What do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` just loops through the array -- it does not create a new array. The map function for the Array prototype in JavaScript loops through the array, performing the logic you provide in the callback function, but returns a new array given the callback as it's result. You can read more about the map function at on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

Hey @jamie you should definitely think of using `map()` for this operation.

Although if want to use `forEach()`, try [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression). It is usually used for emulating private methods with closures.

Have a look at this code

```
var paragraphs = ["this is a p", "%%this is an h2", "%this is an h1"];

/* Using Immediately-Invoked Function Expression */
var newData = (function () {
    var result = []
    paragraphs.forEach(function (x) {
        var header = 0;
        while (x.charAt(header) === "%")
            header++;

        if (header > 0) {
            result.push({type: "h" + header, content: x.slice(header)});
        } else {
            result.push({type: "p", content: x});
        }
    });
    return result;
})();

console.log(newData);

/* Using Map */

var newestData = paragraphs.map(function (x) {
    var header = 0;
    while (x.charAt(header) === "%")
        header++;

    if (header > 0) {
        x = {type: "h" + header, content: x.slice(header)};
    } else {
        x = {type: "p", content: x};
    }
    return x;
});

console.log(newestData);
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tushkiz/rzLXM/1/) for it.